# Mule Flow does not start except when started in a scheduler

Tags: mule, quartz-scheduler

I have another scenario where a flow in an independent process needs to run independently of any scheduled flows. The flow checks for a system property on startup and does a task, after which it stops. However, it fails to start except I add a poller at the start of the flow.  It seems it is prevented from starting because the other flow has an inbound quartz scheduler.

```
 <flow name="system-prop-flow">
   <choice>
     <when expression="#[System.getProprty("dingbert")!=empty]">
    <flow-ref name=""/>
    </when>
   <otherwise>
     ..log something..
   </otherwise>
 </flow> 
  <!-- This seems to cause the top flow from running --> 
  <flow name="schedulededJob">
      <quartz:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Task" 
      cronExpression="0 */2 * * * ?" jobName="mailJob" repeatInterval="0">
             <quartz:event-generator-job/>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
      <component.....
  </flow>
```

Is it possible to have the top flow not run in a quartz scheduler?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. You want `system-prop-flow` to run on start-up? 
Your second flow seems to be running as expected, however from the snippet you gave your top flow will never be called as-is. You must either add an inbound endpoint or use a flow-ref to call it.

Comment: I really want to check a flag and then trigger the flow. Unfortunately it's unclear how I could trigger the flow only once without it being in the scheduler